# After Response.Redirect(), code keeps executing

Tags: c#

The code doesn't stop executing after a redirect with `Response.Redirect()`, which I thought it would(?).
I have tested the Response.Redirect() method by itself, which works (makes a redirect).
I added the second parameter `true` that is supposed to end the script.

I check in debugging that the Redirect is being carried out. The code goes into the if statement, so it is evaluated true.

```
public void OnGet()
    {
        string id = Request.Query["id"];
        if (!int.TryParse(id, out int value) || value == 0)    //<-- true
        {

            Response.Redirect("/Clients/Index", true);        //This line runs
        }
        try                                         //<-- the rest is carried out too
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id = @id";

                using (SqlCommand command = new(sql, connection))

         //etc........
```

The Response is a "`HttpResponse`". It supposedly has an "End" method , but I can't add "`Response.End()`" there is an error saying `"'HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for 'End' and no accessible extension method 'End' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpResponse' could be found"`.

So the code keeps going after the Redirect, and eventually runs into a database exception.

The project is on .net core 6.0 - if that has something to do with it?

Comment: Well, you didn't write an `else` after your `if` so why would you expect it not to run any remaining code you wrote?  You've redirected a Response, but JavaScript itself doesn't magically return from the current function as a result of that.

Comment: Why did you expect the method to suddenly stop? You didn't put a `return;` statement after `Response.Redirect`

Comment: @UnholySheep So I should add a return; then? I wasn't too sure if I can add a return since it's a "void" method.. still getting into c-sharp..
What about the second parameter? "endResponse Boolean - Indicates whether execution of the current page should terminate." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirect?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You can use `return;` to "early out" of a method with a `void` return type. And "current page" does not equal "current method" - the documentation explains what setting the second parameter to `true` does in the **Remarks** section

Comment: `Response.Redirect("/Clients/Index", false);` `Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` is the way to do it. [HttpApplication.CompleteRequest Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest).

Comment: if you want to stop the method use `return`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a Razor page, in which case the comments are wrong: Simply calling return will send the page to the browser.

Instead you should return an `IActionResult`, like this:

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    string id = Request.Query["id"];
    if (!int.TryParse(id, out int value) || value == 0)
    {
        return new RedirectResult("/Clients/Index");        
    }
    try                                         
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id = @id";

            using (SqlCommand command = new(sql, connection))

     //etc........ 
    return Page();
}
```

Now you can redirect and end response or return the page.